# PHP operators in an IF...ElseIf...Else statement. Jumping to Else?

Tags: php

I am trying to use the IF...ElseIf...Else statement which includes basic Logical and Comparison operators. When running the code, instead of looping trough the if statement it echos the else statement only. I followed w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) but had no luck. I am kind of confused now, is there a better way of how to do it please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $currentHour = Date("G");

     echo $currentHour;

     if ($currentHour > "21" && $currentHour < "5")
     {
           echo '<div class="item1" id="night">';
     }
     elseif ($currentHour > "7" && $currentHour < "19")
     {
           echo '<div class="item1" id="day">';
     }
     else
     {
           echo '<div class="item1" id="twilight">';
     }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are comparing (seemingly) numbers to a string, take the quotes away, e.g `$currentHour > 21`, and you should use an `||` (or) operator instead of `&&` (and)

Comment: Even then the value can't be larger than 21 but smaller than 5 at the same time.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ok, I'll concede that, but still, string comparison of numbers?!

Comment: @j08691 I agree, it may be improper and could possibly lead to some edge cases where it doesn't work right - I used to be completely against using w3schools too, but they have gotten better more recently, and they are a huge resource for new programmers

Comment: I see it running correctly. At what time of the day were you testing?

Comment: @icortesi The first IF is not reachable at any time, but the 2nd one is, so I'm guessing OP ran it at some time where the `$currentHour` was not between 7 and 19

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton. I found using the quotes quite odd myself, but I was trying whatever to try and make it work. Apparently the problem was in the statement it self. I will upload my Answer soon. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That's right, OP needs to change and for or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `&&` with `||`.

In your `if` statement, if `$currenthour > 21` then obviously `$currenthour < 5` will fail. Similarly with your `elseif` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Ok managed to figure out my newbie problem, thank you very much for your prompt assistance and help. The if statement was not being reached because I wrote a time that can never be reached. However I wrote a more "simple" syntax which seem to work well.

```
$currentHour = Date("G");
if ($currentHour <= 5)
{
    echo '<div class="item1" id="night">';
}
elseif ($currentHour <= 7)
{
    echo '<div class="item1" id="twilight">';
}
elseif ($currentHour <= 19)
{
    echo '<div class="item1" id="day">';
}
elseif ($currentHour <= 21)
{
    echo '<div class="item1" id="twilight">';
}
elseif ($currentHour > 21) {
    echo '<div class="item1" id="night">';
}
```

Comment: Your first scrpt is better, the problem was with the and operators, they needed to be or.

Comment: This is how I would do it, only one echo needed.  https://www.pastiebin.com/5beb4fee81b99

Comment: Made it cleaner based on your first post.